# Atlassian ] Jira Login Api is not working

Tags: api, authentication, jira

My Atlassian Jira Login API  POST -(https://Domain .atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session) is not working .It is always returning UnAuthorized Response 
   Header 
{"username":"username@xx.com" ,"password":"xxxxx"}

Answer (score 2):

First, the endpoint `/rest/auth/1/session` has been removed from Jira Cloud with the end of last year. See this [announcement by Atlassian from last year](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/).

Second, if you want to authenticate requests to Jira Cloud using Basic Authentication, you need to use an API token for your user. This is also explained in the first sentence of the linked announcement above.

> Atlassian has introduced support for [API tokens](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html?_ga=2.81919894.1877778645.1558613520-798343758.1517998909) for all Atlassian Cloud sites as a replacement for basic authentication requests that previously used a password or primary credential for an Atlassian account, as well as cookie-based authentication.