# Jira Login with REST

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I want to work with Jira using it's REST API but before that I want to do a login with REST API. So far I can find that Login can be done with username and api key token. But I don't want to create API token from portal.
So seeking suggestions if we can create API token from API itself or can do login some way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Atlassian \] Jira Login Api is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254019/atlassian-jira-login-api-is-not-working)

Comment: I tried that but getting "Login failed". For password do I have to use Jira login password or create a API key (as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254019/atlassian-jira-login-api-is-not-working). If API key is the case, I want it work with username and password not API key that we have to generate from Jira dashboards first.

Answer (score 0):

As per Atlassian's [official documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/cookie-based-authentication/), There are multiple ways to authenticate with JIRA. The way you are looking to use is using cookie based authentication.

```
This is how cookie-based authentication works in Jira at a high level:

 - The client creates a new session for the user via the Jira REST API.
 - Jira returns a session object that has information about the session including the session cookie. The client stores this session object.
 - The client can now set the cookie in the header for all subsequent requests to the Jira REST API.
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, as per Step 1, do we have to pass combination of username and password or username and API key generated from Jira dashboard

Comment: @user12251642 you have to pass username and password

Comment: yes, I tried with username, password but it gives me login failes, and 401 response. Just to confirm I am using cloud version, is that for self hosted?